# Rename a file with standard date and time stored in Variables in Python on Ubuntu/Windows

Tags: python, windows, datetime, ubuntu

I asked this question before but some guys divert me on wrong direction and I didn't get the right answer yet.
I Know how to rename the file but I am struggle to add date and time with the new name of file.
Can you plz guide me that how Can I do that?

```
import os
os.rename('mark.txt', 'steve.txt')
```

Comment: Really you want to add the date and time to a string. It's not really to do with files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
print('renaming archive...')
import datetime
dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())
import os
newname = 'danish_'+dt+'.txt'
os.rename('danish.txt', newname)
print('renaming complete...')
```

Comment: Depends on the file system, the generated string cannot be used as a filename. For example, in windows, filename cannot contain `:`.

Comment: `u`? If you can take the time to type out all of that code, you can take the time to hit your `y` and `o` keys as well.

Comment: @falsetru I tried this code on Ubuntu and it is working perfectly... I don't have any idea ab8 windows

Comment: Linux allows you to use ':' characters in a file name, windows doesn't, it is a good habit not to use such characters while programming because most modern programming languages are cross platform

Comment: Also Linux cares for spaces, you'll have to escape them in future references to them, hence it is also a good idea not to use spaces or special characters at all.

Comment: @Digisec your below answer will work on both platform window/linux?

Comment: @Khurram It should. Try it out and if you get into any problems let me know, I'll fix it.

Comment: @lucifer You can use characters like that in Linux filenames, but crossplatform compatibility is not even the major reason to make sure never to do so.

I agree it's nice to maintain cross platform compatibility (/me shakes fist at spaces in filenames and non-case sensitive filesystems), but using those is a disaster even when they are allowed.
It's abominable. So many of those characters are interpreted by the shell in Linux...or not...depending on the context and level of escaping that you'd have to want to be a major pain in the kiester to ever intentionally do so.

Comment: @DoubleD Yes, I apologize for not putting it as clearly that you put it, that precisely was my point, it is a bad programming  technique,programming is taught in a very wrong way in schools, we got to fix that, considering almost the entire world runs on some or the other code

Comment: @lucifer oh for sure, no apology necessary. I was emphatically agreeing with you :-)

Comment: @falsetru, none of the named components can contain a colon, but I think a Windows path can have up to 3 colons, assuming the filesystem supports alternate data streams -- `drive:path:stream:attribute`, e.g. `C:\danish.txt:meta:$DATA`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import os
import time

timestamp = time.strftime('%H%M-%Y%m%d')
os.rename('oldname.txt', 'oldname_%s.txt' % (timestamp))
```

The following will append the timestamp to the file name. You can use this example to expand on it and do whatever you feel like doing. This is a better way then using `datetime.datetime.now()` as, unformatted, that string will contain a space and that is not recommended on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
import os

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
os.rename('mark.txt', 'mark_' + str(current_time) + '.txt')
```

Comment: I don't want current datetime, I want to store starting datetime of my program then wanna that time in the file name content for renaming...

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. 
If you want to put some arbitrary time as a string, then put that in instead of putting in the current time.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

current_time = str(datetime.utcnow())
current_time = "_".join(current_time.split()).replace(":","-")
current_time = current_time[:-7]

os.rename('orfile.txt', 'orfile_'+current_time+'.txt')
```

This will rename the file to the exact timestamp.

```
orfile2015-01-02_16-17-41.txt
```

Please use appropriate variable names it is a bad habit to give names to variables which don't make sense.

Comment: yes, you right it is the good practice to use variable which make good sense

Comment: Python follows Zen philosophy open up your python console and type `import this`.

Comment: Can you plz again explain me that how do I do that step by step... I am using Geany for python compilation

Comment: Hey, python is not a compiled language, it is an interpreted language, open up your terminal, type python and hit enter, it will open the python prompt and then type `import this`
Don't use geany for running python code, use pydev instead, geany is awesome for come quick edits not for a big project

Comment: Your suggestion is appreciated

Comment: CPython does compile Python code, but it creates bytecode that runs in a virtual machine, e.g. look at `dis.dis(compile('import this', '<stdin>', 'single'))`.